# content page with form

Tags: html, asp.net

i have like 4 textbox with required and i have a button name ‘add’ and another button for open a new page .. 
the problem is where i’ m clicking at the button who open the new page they tell me to fill the text box .. is there any way to make the required working just for the « add » button ?
ps: í’m using content place holde and i already triyed to use  but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the line width to zero...

```
series: {
  5: {
    type: 'line',
    lineWidth: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: you helped me a loot really i appreciate that , thank you so much , god bless you

Comment: @BoufousOtman Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @WhiteHat yes yes i really want to do it yesterday but they told me i have to wait 10 min , and after that i forget , sorry ,